# nodejs loop of async calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

in this nodejs function, i create several records in mongodb
using mongoose. the counter counts how many.

```
export function createTimeslots(req, res){
  var startDate = req.body.startDate;
  var Duration = req.body.Duration;
  var repeat = req.body.repeat;
  var counter=0;

  for(var i=0; i<repeat; i++){
    var startTime = ... calculation
    var endTime = ...calculation

    var ts = {
      startTime: startTime,
      endTime: endTime,
    };

    TimeSlot.create(ts, function(err, timeslot){
        counter = counter+1;
    });
  }

  res.status(200).json(counter + ' timeslots created');

}
```

the problem is that the result is always '0 timeslots created'.
i suspect that the create function is async, and by the time it's done,
we are not there any more to update the counter.
So how can i count these records?
(i know i can use the loop's counter, but i plan to do validations
and in some cases not to create the record. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) will help you here:

```
export function createTimeslots(req, res){
  var startDate = req.body.startDate;
  var Duration = req.body.Duration;
  var repeat = req.body.repeat;
  var counter=0;

  var promises = [];

  for(var i=0; i<repeat; i++){
    var startTime = ... calculation
    var endTime = ...calculation

    var ts = {
      startTime: startTime,
      endTime: endTime,
    };

    promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve) {
      TimeSlot.create(ts, function(err, timeslot) {
        counter = counter+1;
        resolve();
      });
    }));
  }

  Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
      res.status(200).json(counter + ' timeslots created');
  });
}
```

This will wait until all asynchronous operations have been completed, and only then continue and create the return message.

Comment: you should probably also do something with rejecting the promise on error

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

counter is set to 0 every time u call createTimeslots, so make it a model varible

```html
var counter=0;
export function createTimeslots(req, res){
  var startDate = req.body.startDate;
  var Duration = req.body.Duration;
  var repeat = req.body.repeat;
 
  for(var i=0; i<repeat; i++){
    var startTime = ... calculation
    var endTime = ...calculation

    var ts = {
      startTime: startTime,
      endTime: endTime,
    };

    TimeSlot.create(ts, function(err, timeslot){
        counter = counter+1;
    });
  }
  
  res.status(200).json(counter + ' timeslots created');

}
```

Comment: counter is incremented in an async function, which might not have executed by the time `res.status` line is called.
at best this is a race condition, at worst, this wont work.

Comment: This is not going to solve the problem if the callback is run asynchronously.

Comment: case counter is incremented in an async function, use promise @mkoryak as TimoSta did

Comment: it is async. question says mongodb

Comment: @mkoryak u mean in this request, i thought u want in total, it is not clear

Answer (score -1):

Move the counter outside the body of the async callback you are passing to the TimeSlot create method.

```
export function createTimeslots(req, res){
  var startDate = req.body.startDate;
  var Duration = req.body.Duration;
  var repeat = req.body.repeat;
  var counter=0;


  for(var i=0; i<repeat; i++){
    var startTime = ... calculation
    var endTime = ...calculation

    var ts = {
      startTime: startTime,
      endTime: endTime,
    };

    counter = counter+1;

    TimeSlot.create(ts, function(err, timeslot){
        // do stuff with counter

    });
  }

  res.status(200).json(counter + ' timeslots created');
```

}

Comment: except if the creation failed, this lies